# Trying To figure out the datetime format and converting str to pandas datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

So I have a column in a dataframe, which stores datetime in this format '2016-04-29T00:00:00Z'. Also the type is string, I would like to convert this to pandas datetime using `pd.to_datetime(df['column_name'], format="YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ")`. Can you please provide the correct format for this. I am getting this error.

[image]

Comment: You can use `pd.to_datetime(df['column_name'])`

Comment: btw. the format you have is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)